# C program weird behavior

Tags: c, debugging, ida, cracking

Hello guys this is my first question on stack
I am very noob to c language but i am decompling simple crackme me from crackme.one
https://crackmes.one/crackme/62072dd633c5d46c8bcbfd9b
I opened it in Ida and get this source c code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  int v3; // eax
  int v4; // eax
  char nptr; // [rsp+1Fh] [rbp-11h] BYREF
  int v6; // [rsp+20h] [rbp-10h]
  int i; // [rsp+24h] [rbp-Ch]

  if ( argc != 2 )
  {
    printf("Usage : %s <license pass code here [numbers only]>\n", *argv);
    exit(0);
  }
  v6 = 0;
  for ( i = 0; ; ++i )
  {
    v4 = strlen(argv[1]);
    if ( i >= v4 )
      break;
    nptr = argv[1][i];
    v3 = atoi(&nptr);
    v6 += v3;
  }
  if ( v6 == 50 )
  {
    puts("Premium access has been activated !");
    exit(0);
  }
  printf("Wrong license code");
  exit(0);
}
```

I easyly discovered that key code must be serial of numbers that their sum is 50 i wrote a python program to guess the key and the weird is key like 5555555555 works but not 55555555532 although sum is 50
Please someone point out to where is this behavior coming from ?

Comment: The code shown relies on undefined behaviour.  That may be hurting you.  It treats the single character `nptr` as a string, but you can't null-terminate a single byte.  At minimum, print the 'string' in `nptr` to see what's happening; print the value in `v3` to see what `atoi()` returns.  Print `v6` to see what it holds.

Comment: thanks for your response i printed every thing as the program run and found the problem is with key 55555555532 at last number it make v3 as 20 not 2 as expected

Comment: So, now you know why undefined behaviour is to be avoided at all costs.  The code needs to use `char nptr[2] = "";` to zero the array, and then use `nptr[0] = argv[1][i];` and `v3 = atoi(nptr);` and your problem should be cured.